# What's the best way to manage REST requests when each record requires multiple GET calls?

Tags: node.js, rest

I have to consume data from a 3rd party app that exposes various GET endpoints. For each record, I need to get info like `firstName`, `lastName`, and `email`. Unfortunately, all 3 pieces of data are spread across 2 endpoints.

1. 1 call to get an array of users and their first and last names
2. 1 call per user to get additional info for each user (in this case, their email)

If I have a list of 10 users, I'd need to make 11 calls (1 for the user list + 1 per user), which is not ideal.

What's the best way to solve this problem? Is the only way to basically loop through the user list and make a GET call for each user?

Comment: Are any of the endpoints nested? /person?=names/email

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax They're not :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Node.js you can fire off many HTTP requests in parallel.

I don't know what the state of HTTP/2 clients in node is, but if you find a good HTTP2 clients, these requests can all be multiplexed over a single connection. This is gonna be pretty fast.

There is still a per-HTTP request overhead, even with HTTP2... but that overhead becomes smaller.